# Arduino Uno with SD, Cardinfo sketch how to list only visible files

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card

There are two files (that can be seen on my computer) on my sd card, `6.bmp` and `example.txt` (the latter written from my arduino). I have them connected to my arduino via LCSTUDIO breakout board (which surprisingly caused me no trouble at all).

When I run the example "cardinfo" sketch, the files it lists includes those two files along with tons of others, which I assume are just invisible from a personal computer.

How would I list only the files that can be seen from my computer (i.e. aren't inside any directory, but are just plain in the SD card)?

Using arduino UNO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Answer: Don't think you can

Long Answer: Dont think you can, because, unlike an OS like windows, mac, linux, etc. The arduino just tales all the files. You could save those two files and format it as FAT16 though, then add the 2 files back on the sd and there you go.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna go ahead and accept this,

Comment: Probably the best answer I can get for something thats apparently impossible,